# 2 similar Highstocks multiple data-series still tooltip and functionality not the same

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Can somebody please look at both the examples below and see why the first one is working and not the second one ..

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2bUTX

```
var dataAr = [[1390181580000, 3],[1390181520000, 2],[1390181460000, 1]];
```

Not working: The tooltip just shows up for a couple of points randomly but I can't scroll to each point with this. Any help would be really appreciate.

Not working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/PPg6z

```
var dataAr = [[1317889560000, 3.3],[1317889620000, 2.6],[1317889680000, 1.5]];
```

Comment: Open JS console, you have error: `Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15 `

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your data via x,ascending.